# Creating a PDF File from some specific data in HTML Tags in a website in Safari

Tags: applescript, safari, pdf, printing, automation

I have the following task that I need to automate as much as possible:

1. Grab Page Source from currently open site in Safari.  This is a site whose HTML structure is fixed, but specific data (such as ID numbers or names) might change
2. Grab a few specific data points within the HTML.  Look for patterns such as:

`<span class="help-block" style="color: green; font-size: medium;" id="id_invoice"><strong>ID #:</strong> XXXXX</span>` to get an invoice number XXXXX

or

`<span class="help-block" style="color: green; font-size: medium;" id="date_time">2023-02-20 14:33:46</span>` to get a YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss timestamp

3. Create a PDF file of specific proportions and include said Data in a nicely formatted way (probably going thorough Pages?)
4. Print said PDF file

What I think would be the best case scenario, would be to build an AppleScript that I can expose via the Services Menu in Safari, and have it automatically do all of the previous steps, landing me immediately on the macOS print dialog.

Suggestions?

---

Main attempt was this Applescript:

```
-- Get the URL of website, just for test purposes, I hadn't gotten around to the script getting the URL directly from Safari

set websiteURL to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the URL of the website you want to extract data from:" default answer "")

-- Get the tags that contain the data

set idInvoice to text returned of "id_invoice"


-- Open the website in Safari and wait for it to load, again test purposes, shouldn't apply if exposed as Service
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:websiteURL}
    repeat while (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is not "complete"
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell

-- Get the values of the fields
tell application "Safari"
    set idInvoice to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('" & idInvoice & "')[0].innerText" in document 1
    end tell

-- Create the PDF file
set fileName to "Invoice.pdf"
set filePath to (path to desktop as string) & fileName
set theDate to current date
set formattedDate to (month of theDate as integer) & "/" & day of theDate & "/" & year of theDate

tell application "Pages"
    activate
    make new document
    tell front document
        set body text of body text box 1 to "Invoice: " & idInvoice & return " & formattedDate
        set thePageSetup to the page setup
        set the page width of thePageSetup to 8.5
        set the page height of thePageSetup to 11
        set the left margin of thePageSetup to 0.5
        set the right margin of thePageSetup to 0.5
        set the top margin of thePageSetup to 0.5
        set the bottom margin of thePageSetup to 0.5
        set the orientation of thePageSetup to portrait
        export front document to filePath as PDF
    end tell
end tell

-- Open the PDF file in Preview
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open filePath
end tell
```

---

Issues/questions:

1. How can I feed the current URL to the script, from the Services menu?
2. The way it's written, it's loading the site in a new Safari window, obviously unnecessary
3. Not sure what to put in the `-- Get the values of the fields` section to correctly get the data out of the HTML section.  Currently, in my tests, variable doesn't get assigned